# Simple way to limit characters in ng-bind-html Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to limit the characters i see on my angular js app. Currently i am using:

```
<p ng-bind-html="item.get('Content') | limitTo: 150"></p>
```

But no joy, any ideas...

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that will work with ng-bind-html. This is for binding actual html code to the page. ng-bind should work fine.

```
<p ng-bind="item.get('Content') | limitTo: 150"></p>
```

See plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/y0LXMMFi6sU9AhShvuha?p=preview

EDIT:

Since you do have HTML code in it, you'll need to use ngSanitize. You can read about that here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize

Add the reference to angular-sanitize.js, then import it into the app

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngSanitize']);
```

Then your original code should work fine, although it's likely parts of it will be cut off, including ending tags, so you'll need to deal with that.

See plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/y0LXMMFi6sU9AhShvuha?p=preview

Comment: You are assuming the op is using ng-bind-html for no reason... why?

Comment: He wants to limit the characters on the page... that hints pure text to me. If he wants to add divs and such with the code he'll have to use a totally different approach. <div> adds 5 characters plus another 6 for </div>. If I'm wrong, then this isn't the correct answer, but only the OP knows that for certain.

Comment: Hey Guys, the data is being brought in from Parse, which has html tags in their... so that is why I am using ng-bind-html

Comment: See my edit, unless you're already doing that and only want to limit the characters shown, which as I type this, I assume is the scenario.... Is that correct?

Comment: Hi Timothy, I am already using nGSanitize and the original code i pasted was not working....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83349/discussion-between-sole-and-timothy).

Comment: What about showing the first **paragraph** only? How would you do that?

Answer (score 3):

since you use `ng-bind-html` you also need `$sce`, so my advice do it in your controller. Like so

```
Ctrl.$inject= ['$sce', '$filter', '$scope'];
Function Ctrl($sce, $filter, $scope) {
  $scope.content= $filter('limitTo')(dataWithHtml, 100, 0);
  $scope.content= $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.content);
}
```

on html you can use like so:

```
<p ng-bind-html="content"></p>
```

in this case I assume your original data is `dataWithHtml`, 100 is the limit number, 0 is the starting point. More details please refer to official documentations.

Answer (score 3):

integrate this link :

```
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
```

check if you have sanitize here

```
var adminApp = angular.module('adminApp', ['ngSanitize', ...,])
```

in your html you macke this code :

```
<p ng-bind-html="item.get('Content') | limitTo: 150"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller

`$scope.contentText = item.get('Content');`

In your html

`<p>{{ contentText | limitTo: 150 }} </p>`

Comment: This doesn't use ng-bind-html

Answer (score 0):

Inject `$sce` into your controller and then use it like below:

```
$scope.contentText = $sce.trustAsHtml(item.get('Content'));
```

In your html

```
<p ng-bind-html="contentText | limitTo: 150"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this without function if you are using **sanitize** filter

```
<p ng-bind-html="message  | limitTo: 150 | sanitize"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If none of the answers above didn't satisfy you, how about the following approach?

```
var app = angular.module('myTestNgApp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('myMainTestCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.longText = "This is a very loooooooooooooooooooong text";
})
.filter('textShortenerFilter', function() {
  return function(text, length) {
    if (text.length > length) {
      return text.substr(0, length) + "...";
    }
    return text;
  }
});
```

Working example:- https://jsfiddle.net/anjanasilva/8xk9eL0t/

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom directive and filters which will work same as ng-bind-html

```
<p to-html>{{content | limitTo:200}}</P>
```

directive:

```
.directive('toHtml', function($timeout,$sce) {
   return {
          restrict: 'A',
          link: function($scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
             $timeout(function() {
                element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(element[0].innerText) || '');
             }, 200);
          }
         };
})
```

Truncate with ellipsis:

```
<p to-html>{{content | limitWithEllipsis:200}}</P>
```

you need to use custom filter(limitWithEllipsis) with above directive

```
.filter('limitWithEllipsis', function() {
          return function(input, limit, begin) {
              var str='';
                if (Math.abs(Number(limit)) === Infinity) {
                  limit = Number(limit);
                } else {
                  limit = parseInt(limit);
                }
                if (isNaN(limit)) return input;

                if (angular.isNumber(input)) input = input.toString();
                if (!angular.isArray(input) && !angular.isString(input)) return input;
                if(input.length<=limit) return input;
                begin = (!begin || isNaN(begin)) ? 0 : parseInt(begin);
                begin = (begin < 0) ? Math.max(0, input.length + begin) : begin;

                if (limit >= 0) {
                  str=input.slice(begin, begin + limit);
                  return str.concat('....'); 
                } else {
                  if (begin === 0) {
                     str=input.slice(limit, input.length);
                    return str.concat('....');
                  } else {
                     str=input.slice(Math.max(0, begin + limit), begin);
                    return str.concat('....');
                  }
                }
            };
        })
```