# Truncate ng-bind-html in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, truncate

I'm using truncate.js https://github.com/sparkalow/angular-truncate and it works great for codes like this:

```
{{announcement.content | characters:25}}
```

However, i can't seem to setup for the following and i can't get it to work:

```
<p ng-bind-html="parseTrustedHtml(announcement.content | characters : 25)"></p>
```

Comment: can you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: I'm not sure if i can. I couldn't install the angular.js on jsFiddle :(

Comment: Could you provide a parseTrustedHtml function? Try $filter('characters') in an controller function.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar issue, the issue is that angular-truncate is meant for strings, not HTML. Here is my solution:

Markup:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="parentCtrl">
   <div ng-bind-html="text | limitHtml : maxNumberOfChar:'...' | trustAsHtml"></div>
</div>
```

Code:

```
    .filter('trustAsHtml', ['$sce', function($sce) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml;
    }])
    .filter('limitHtml', function() {
        return function(text, limit, ellipsis) {
            var _getClosedTagsString = function(_tagArray) {
                var _returnArray = [],
                _getTagType = function(_string) {
                    return _string.replace(/<[\/]?([^>]*)>/,"$1");
                };

                angular.forEach(_tagArray,function(_tag,_i) {
                    if(/<\//.test(_tag)) {
                        if(_i === 0) {
                            _returnArray.push(_tag);
                        } else if(_getTagType(_tag) !== _getTagType(_tagArray[_i - 1])) {
                            _returnArray.push(_tag);
                        }
                    }
                });
                return _returnArray.join('');
            },
            _countNonHtmlCharToLimit = function(_text,_limit) {
                var _isMarkup = false,
                _isSpecialChar = false,
                _break = false,
                _underLimit = false,
                _totalText = 0,
                _totalChar = 0,
                _element,
                _return = {
                    textCounter   : 0,
                    offsetCounter : 0,
                    setEllipsis   : false,
                    overElementArray : []
                };
                angular.forEach(_text,function(_c) {
                    _underLimit = _return.textCounter < _limit;
                    if(_c === '<' && !_isMarkup && !_isSpecialChar) {
                        (!_underLimit) && (_element = '<');
                        _isMarkup = true;
                    } else if(_c === '&' && !_isMarkup && !_isSpecialChar) {
                        _isSpecialChar = true;
                    } else if(_isMarkup) {
                        //tracking html elements that are beyond the text limit
                        (!_underLimit) && (_element = _element + _c);
                        if(_c === '>') {
                            //push element in array if it is complete, and we are
                            //beyond text limit, to close any html that is unclosed
                            (!_underLimit) && (_return.overElementArray.push(_element));
                            _break = true;
                            _isMarkup = false;
                        }
                    } else if(_c === ';' && _isSpecialChar) {
                        _isSpecialChar = false;
                        //count as one character
                        _return.textCounter++;
                        _break = true;
                    }

                    if(_underLimit) {
                        if(!_isMarkup && !_isSpecialChar && !_break) {
                            //counting number of characters in non html string
                            _return.textCounter++;
                        }
                        _return.offsetCounter++;
                    } else {
                        _return.setEllipsis = true
                    }
                    _break = false;

                });

                //returns offset within html of number of non html characters found
                return _return;
            },
            _charToLimitOutput = _countNonHtmlCharToLimit(text.toString(),limit);

            return text.toString().substr(0, _charToLimitOutput.offsetCounter) +
                ellipsis + _getClosedTagsString(_charToLimitOutput.overElementArray);
        }
    })
    .controller('parentCtrl', function($scope,$timeout) {
        $scope.text = "<span><h1>Example&nbsp;</h1><p>Special Text</p><div>other stuff</div></span>";
        $scope.maxNumberOfChar = 10;
    });
```

Comment: This code is amazing. Thanks so much @koolunix!

Answer (score 1):

No need to use truncate.js
You can solve this using custom directives and filters.
try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45076560/6816707

Answer (score 0):

Need more information, however can you check if parseTrustedHtml method/function is available at $scope or $rootscope.